# TouchID - Fallback with Pattern Lock and deployment target?

Tags: design-patterns, deployment, target, touch-id

I want to use TouchID in my app. My app already uses a pattern lock system to lock the app. You swipe a pattern to unlock, like it is known from android devices.

Now I wanted to integrate TouchID. If I get it right, you have to use a fallback system when you use TouchID and it can not be the passcode you use to unlock the phone if TouchID fails, so you have to implement your own system right?

My question is, if I could use my already existing pattern lock system as the fallback instead of a passcode/password?

If yes, I would like to know if I can get rid of the "Enter password" button, because it is not a password in my case, it is a pattern. I read that you can just assign an empty string to it, and it disappears. I would show TouchID above the pattern lock window and if the user does not want TouchID he can press Cancel, TouchID will be dismissed and he can just use the pattern lock system. Will this pass app store review?

Another question is about the deployment target. There is really no documentation about it, or I didn t find it at least. My app has deployment target 7.0 and I would like to stay with that because 40% of the users are still on iOS 7. I am a bit confused about it. TouchID worked already in iOS7, but for developers it came with iOS8. So what does that mean? Can I just stay with deployment target 7.0, implement TouchID and it will work on iOS7 devices like iPhone 5s with iOS 7 installed? Or do I have to check for version and only use TouchID if the user is on iOS8?

Thanks for your help !